# Issue with typescript path resolution. (Error: Cannot find module '[module_name]')

Tags: typescript, typescript-module-resolution

I have a node project setup with typescript. Everything worked perfectly fine, but lately I've been wanting to implement path resolution.
Why is it such a hassle?

Here is my project architecture:

```
└───src
    ├───models
    ├──────Person.ts
    ├───query
    ├──────index.ts
    └───index.ts
├───package.json
└───tsconfig.json
```

My tsconfig is setup like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@models/*": [ "models/*" ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [ "node_modules", "build" ],
  "include": [ "src/**/*.ts" ],
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine within VS-code.
I can easily import Person.ts from my index file using:

```
import Person from '@models/Person'.
```

tsc builds without any errors or warnings.

But when I run

```
node build/index.js
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@models/Person'
```

It seems like paths are not correctly converted after typescript compilation.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I finally went for:
I've added [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and [tsconfig-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) to my `package.json`.
Allowing me to run my project like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env TS_NODE_BASEURL=./build node --require tsconfig-paths/register ./build/index.js",
  "build": "tsc",
  "watch": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"yarn start\""
},
```

Note here that I'm using the `cross-env` package only because I'm on windows.

I still don't understand why path resolving isn't native to typescript compilation but anyways. It works like a charm! and on both Linux&Windows